# Generating a Color Palette From Image using P5 javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, pixel, p5.js

I am ask to indentify the top 5 repeating colors from an image.

I have the following code, provided by my teacher

```
for(let j=0 ; j < theImage.pixels.length ;j++) {

    let r = theImage.pixels[j];
    let g = theImage.pixels[j+1]
    let b = theImage.pixels [j+2]


    let temp = colors.find((element) => {
        return element.color[0] == r &&
        element.color[1] == g &&
        element.color[2] == b;
    });


    if (!temp) {
        colors.push({ color: [r, g, b], amount: 1});  
    } else {
        temp.amount += 1; 
        //console.log(colors);
    }

}
```

I understand how i'm moving through all the pixels and the process of adding element to a stack but I don't understand how to identify the top five colors and save them. I suppose it has to related to the amount counter that gets increased every time it finds the element but I don't even know what am I working with , arrays? Objects? normal values? What am I looking for and how do I save those values

Gonna leave a link to my code here if someone wants to check it and run it.Thanks in advance

https://editor.p5js.org/isvr95/sketches/oe6efUW9r

P.D. Don't run it, it will freeze your tab.

Answer (score 3):

Without modifying your code too much I came up with this:

```js
let theImage
let colors = []
function preload(){
  theImage = loadImage('https://picsum.photos/150')
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(200, 150)
  image(theImage, 0, 0)
  theImage.loadPixels()
  
  for(let j=0 ; j < theImage.pixels.length ;j+=4) {

    let r = theImage.pixels[j];
    let g = theImage.pixels[j+1]
    let b = theImage.pixels [j+2]


    let temp = colors.find((element) => {
        return element.color[0] == r &&
        element.color[1] == g &&
        element.color[2] == b;
    });


    if (!temp) {
        colors.push({ color: [r, g, b], amount: 1});  
    } else {
        temp.amount += 1; 
    }
    colors = colors.sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount)
  }
  
  fill(colors[0].color)
  rect(150, 0, 50, 30)
  fill(colors[1].color)
  rect(150, 30, 50, 30)
  fill(colors[2].color)
  rect(150, 60, 50, 30)
  fill(colors[3].color)
  rect(150, 90, 50, 30)
  fill(colors[4].color)
  rect(150, 120, 50, 30)
}
/**/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Your algorithm stores each color and the amount of times it is found but when traversing the pixels doesn't take into account that the value of each pixel's color takes four places in the array (assuming pixel density of 1), that's why I set the increment to be `j += 4`. Then, all that needs to be done is to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `colors` array by the `amount` value of its objects, in a descending manner:

```
colors = colors.sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount)
```

and pick the first five elements, which will be the ones that are repeated the most.

Basically you are working with an array that contains objects that contain both an array and a primitive data type:

```
[
    {
        color: [],
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        color: [],
        amount: 1
    }
    ...
]
```

When you run the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method you are searching for a `color` by matching all the RGB values; if its found then adds to its amount value: `temp.amount += 1` and, if it isn't, it creates a new color object and adds it to the array  `colors.push({ color: [r, g, b], amount: 1})`